# "sws_scale_frame" function not found in libswscale/swscale.h

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-processing, transcoding, swscale

I am trying to scale a video from 1080p to 480p. However, whenever I am calling `sws_scale_frame()` function, I keep getting undefined reference. When I checked the header file, I found that the function signature is missing from the header file. I have installed `libswscale` using the command `sudo apt install libswscale-dev`. If this is not the right appoarch, can anyone help with how to get the function or alternative if this is deprecated?

P.S. My build options in VS Code are as follows:  `"-lavformat","-lavcodec","-lswscale","-lavutil", "-lm", "-lpthread"`

EDIT: Version of libswscale-dev is `7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1` if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libswscale-dev_4.4.2` is actually too old, and doesn't yet support `sws_scale_frame()`.

I think `sws_scale_frame()` was added in FFmpeg version 5.0 (and version 4.4.2 applies FFmpeg version 4.4.2 or so).

The [following page](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/02/install-ffmpeg-5-0-ubuntu/) has instructions for installing FFmpeg version 5.0 on Ubuntu.

What worked for me is (for upgrading `libswscale-dev`):

`sudo apt install ppa-purge`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg5`

`sudo apt install libswscale-dev`

We better also install FFmpeg 5:

`sudo apt install ffmpeg`

---

Now the file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale/` has declaration of the function:

```
int sws_scale_frame(struct SwsContext *c, AVFrame *dst, const AVFrame *src);
```

---

Note:
I tested with Ubuntu 18.04, and installing FFmpeg 5 was not working.

Comment: See doc/APIchanges - the frame based API was added on 2021-09-06 in 42cd64c1826